# Give apache write access to DocumentRoot on dev server

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, unix, user-permissions

I've got apache running on my mac workstation (OS X 10.7, with the pre-installed copy of apache), and our web applications require write access to certain sections of the filesystem to run (usually just a tmp dir, but sometimes more than that).

We have (literally) thousands of clients, and I want to be able to quickly grab a copy of any website's code, and have it "just work", however I always need to manually modify the unix permissions of specific directories after pulling a client's website out of source control (the list of directories varies from one client to another, as it has changed over the years).

Since it's a dev server, firewalled off from the general internet, I would like to give apache/php write access to the entire DocumentRoot. How can I do this?

I tried `chmod 777` on the DocumentRoot, but if I create a directory inside it, the permissions are still `755` (owner: `me`, group: `wheel`).

I think there should be a way to force all files created inside DocumentRoot to be 777 or perhaps 775, with the `_www` user added to the `wheel` group?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by using ACL's, which supports inherited permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R +a '_www allow read,write,delete,add_file,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit' /Library/WebServer/Documents
```

Now, whenever I create a new directory or source control checkout in the `DocumentRoot`, the `_www` user has full read/write access.

Answer (score 1):

setting your umask to 000 or 002 will give you the 777 or 775 create permissions you're looking for.  Problem is, anything you create anywhere will get those permissions.  If you're ok with 775, go for it. In not, you could make a mkwebdir command like so:

```
mkwebdir()
{
  umask 000;
  mkdir "$1";
  umask 022;
}
```

or even better, if you don't mind a sudo command in there:

```
mkwebdir()
{
  mkdir "$1" && sudo chown _www "$1"
}
```

then just do:  mkwebdir username

Comment: I'm hoping for a more seamless solution than creating a shell script. I don't typically use mkdir to create directories, I typically use subversion or git or my IDE, sometimes I also use `cp -r`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `chown _www:wheel` docroot and then `chmod g+s` after that setup umask as you need.